# React Native Maps animate to bearing after initial render

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to call a method on the map right after the component first renders. In this case `this.map` is undefined, but shouldn't it be set by the ref? How do I get a reference to the MapView in the componentDidMount method?

```
import React from 'react';
import { MapView } from 'expo';

export default class Map extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.map.animateToBearing(25)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MapView
        ref={ref => { this.map = ref }}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        mapType="satellite"
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: 39.2741004,
          longitude: -76.6502307,
          latitudeDelta: 0.002,
          longitudeDelta: 0.001,
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this [Github issue](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/issues/1003), you probably have to use `onLayout` instead of `componentDidMount`.

For example:

```
<MapView
    ref={ref => { this.map = ref }}
    onLayout={() => this.map.animateToBearing(25)}
    ....
/>
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error that _this2.map.animateToBearing is not a function

Comment: @pjb3 what if you try the `MapView` from [`airbnb/react-native-maps`](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps)? Perhaps the `MapView` bundled in `expo` is an older version

Answer (score 0):

```
    const [heading, setHeading] = useState(0);

    const cameraView = {
        center: {
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: lng,
        },
        pitch: 10,
        heading: heading,
        altitude: 1,
        zoom: 15
    };

    let getHeading = () => {
        Location.watchHeadingAsync(value => {
            setHeading(value.magHeading)
        });
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        initialLocation();
        getHeading();
    }, [])
```

By using watchHeadingAsync you can update the heading constantly.